# Download a Blob in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, rest, azure

I have created an Azure Cloud Service with a WCF REST service. I am working on the local storage development with blobs. At this time, I've been able to upload files from my computer in containers and list them as well in a Listbox1. Now, i need to select an item(blob) from my Listbox1 and download the selected item.
Here's my code:

```
public void DownloadBlob(AzureDataContract download) {
    // Connect to the storage account's blob endpoint 
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureStorageConnectionString"));
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    // Create the blob storage container 
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(download.ContainerName);
    container.CreateIfNotExists();

    // Create the blob in the container 
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test");

    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(download.FilePath))
    {
        blob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Then i am trying to call my method using JQuery and Ajax as follow:

```js
$('#btnDownload').click(function() {
  var download = {
    "ContainerName": $("#listContainer").val(),
    "FilePath": $("#listBlob option:selected").val()
  };
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:49416/AzureService.svc/DownloadBlob",
    data: JSON.stringify(download),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    processData: true,
    success: function(data) {
      alert("downloading");
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert("error");
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Is there any error you're getting?

Comment: Yes, i have this problem:
An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\' is denied.
I have create an input where i set my path

Answer (score 1):

At this moment your DownloadBlob function is not returning anything. It is a void function. So your client will never receive the blob. What it is doing at the moment is writing the blob to a file on the server disk (download.FilePath). If you want to download anything in your rest call, you should return the file to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. After running, the blob file should have been downloaded to your 'FilePath' location. 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' normally happened when you have no right to delete/create a file under a folder. I think you can check if you have write access to "FilePath' position.